# How to resize Popup Window dynamically at runtime?

Tags: delphi

I try to create a custom Combobox control that popups a Treeview.
Everything looks fine.
But when i try to add runtime resize functionality to that control, the popup window (Treeview) just move and won't change its size.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Snippets for Popup Window :

**On Create** :

```
ControlStyle := ControlStyle + [csNoDesignVisible, csReplicatable, csDoubleClicks];
```

**On Create Params** :

```
begin
  inherited CreateParams(Params);
  with Params do
  begin
    Style := Style or WS_POPUP or WS_VSCROLL or WS_BORDER;
    ExStyle := WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW;
    AddBiDiModeExStyle(ExStyle);
    //WindowClass.Style := CS_SAVEBITS; {this would prevent ondoubleclick event}
  end;
```

On Mouse Move :

```
var
  ARect, RR: TRect;
  DragStyle: TDragStyle;
  Procedure SetDragStyle(ds:TDragStyle; c:TCursor);
  begin
    FDragStyle:=ds;
    Cursor:=c;
  end;
begin
  inherited;
  FMouseMoveSelected := GetNodeAt(x, y);
  if FDragged then begin
    case FDragStyle of
       dsSizeLeft :begin
                      SetWindowPos(Handle, HWND_TOP, Left+(x-FDragPos.X), Top, Width, Height,
                        SWP_NOACTIVATE or SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
                      //Left:=Left+(x-FDragPos.X); {alternate code that doesn't work either}
                   end;
    end;
    FDragPos:=Point(x,y);
  end else begin
    SetDragStyle(dsMove,crDefault);
    ARect := GetClientRect;
    RR:=ARect;
    InflateRect(RR,-2,-2);
    if (x>=0) and (x<=Width) and (y>=0) and (y<=Height) and (not PtInRect(RR,Point(x,y))) then begin
      if (x<=RR.Left) then begin
        //if (y<=RR.Top) then SetDragStyle(dsSizeTopLeft,crSizeNWSE)else
        if (y>=RR.Bottom) then SetDragStyle(dsSizeBottomLeft,crSizeNESW)
        else SetDragStyle(dsSizeLeft,crSizeWE); 
      end else if (x>=RR.Right) then begin
        //if (y<=RR.Top) then SetDragStyle(dsSizeTopRight,crSizeNESW) else
        if (y>=RR.Bottom) then SetDragStyle(dsSizeBottomRight,crSizeNWSE)
        else SetDragStyle(dsSizeRight,crSizeWE);
      end else begin
        //if (y<=RR.Top) then SetDragStyle(dsSizeTop,crSizeNS) else
        if (y>=RR.Bottom) then SetDragStyle(dsSizeBottom,crSizeNS)
        else SetDragStyle(dsMove,crDefault);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
end;
```

**On Mouse Down** :

```
begin
  inherited;
  if FDragStyle<>dsMove then begin
    FDragPos:=point(x,y);
    FDragged:=true;
  end;
end;
```

**On Mouse Up** :

```
begin
  inherited;
  FDragged:=false;
end;
```

Comment: Why don't you set the WS_THICKFRAME style and be done with it?

Comment: yeah, right. Very good suggestion. It resized without need my code on mouse events. I've tried that. Now, the problem is it resizes all direction, so i should implement additional routines to prevent resizing from left and top. **Thanks**.

Comment: You're welcome. Whether you use it or not, I posted an answer for what I believe was wrong.

Comment: If you want it to resize for only some of the edges, you might find a search on WM_NCHITTEST useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mixing client coordinates with screen coordinates in the `SetWindowPos` call. That's because you're floating a window that's not supposed to float and the VCL has no knowledge of it. When you refer to its `Left`, the VCL returns a coordinate relative to its parent, probably the form. Also don't change the point you saved while you started to drag during the drag (that being FDragPos):

```
procedure TPanel.MouseMove(Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var
  ARect, RR: TRect;
  DragStyle: TDragStyle;

  Procedure SetDragStyle(ds:TDragStyle; c:TCursor);
  begin
    FDragStyle:=ds;
    Cursor:=c;
  end;

  var
    DragOffset: Integer;
begin
  inherited;
  FMouseMoveSelected := GetNodeAt(x, y);
  if FDragged then begin
    case FDragStyle of
       dsSizeLeft:
         begin
            DragOffset := X - FDragPos.X;
            winapi.windows.GetWindowRect(Handle, ARect);
            SetWindowPos(Handle, HWND_TOP,
                                  ARect.Left + DragOffset,
                                  ARect.Top,
                                  ARect.Right - ARect.Left - DragOffset,
                                  ARect.Bottom - ARect.Top,
                                  SWP_NOACTIVATE or SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
            //Left:=Left+(x-FDragPos.X); {alternate code that doesn't work either}
         end;
    end;
//    FDragPos:=Point(x,y);  // do not change drag origin while you're dragging
  end else begin
    ..
```

Comment: Thanks  for that snippet. That absolutely answer my question with some modifications : (1) **FDragPos:=Point(x,y)** should be set on Bottom and BottomRight DragStyle, and **FDragPos.y:=y** on BottomLeft DragStyle. (2) We must capture handle (**setcapture(handle)**) on mouse button down event or the resize will not perform while moving cursor away. Once again, thanks.